# How to save TDigest to Hive external table from dataframe with spark3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark3

I have dataframe in spark3 that contains rows with TDigest type from [isarnProject](https://github.com/isarn/isarn-sketches). TDigest itself is spark UDT and perfectly serialised in parquet, but I have no idea how to save it to external table in hive. (except write parquets to table location and repartition - colleagues say that it can be slow than df.insertInto(tableName) operation).

## What I did:

Below I place some scala code for my case.

```
      val data = spark.createDataFrame(Vector.fill(1000) {
        (nextInt(10), nextGaussian)
      })
      val udf1 = TDigestAggregator.udf[Double](compression = 0.2, maxDiscrete = 25)
      val agg = data.agg(udf1($"_1").as("td1"), udf1($"_2").as("td2"))
      agg.printSchema()
//      root
//      |-- td1: tdigest (nullable = true)
//      |-- td2: tdigest (nullable = true)
```

So, when I call `agg.write.insertInto(realTableName)` I get exception:

```
- Cannot write 'td1': struct<compression:double,maxDiscrete:int,cent:array<double>,mass:array<double>> is incompatible with struct<compression:double,maxDiscrete:int,cent:array<double>,mass:array<double>>
```

resultTableName was created by this script

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tableName (
          td1 struct<compression:double,maxDiscrete:int,cent:array<double>,mass:array<double>>, 
          td2 struct<compression:double,maxDiscrete:int,cent:array<double>,mass:array<double>>
        )
         STORED AS PARQUET
         LOCATION someLocation
```

The core reason of this error is wrong type interpretation at org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType (line 466) from spark. Is this bug or exits way to handle it?

## WA:

save as parquet in the table location;